# how to select parent div with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have applied this jquery

HTML :

```
    <div class="slider sliderclick" style="left: -200px;">
        <div class="button-wrap">
            <div class="content-wrap" id="button-1">Special Offer Content</div>
            <div class="controller">
                <div>
                    <a href="#buttton-1">Special Offer</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

JS :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".controller a").click(function () {        

        jQuery('.slider').animate({left:'0px'},1000);
        //tried this but not worked
        //jQuery(this).parent('.slider').animate({left: '0px'},1000);
        return false;

    });

});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p9jTf/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) in your case :

```
jQuery(this).closest('.slider').animate({left: '0px'},1000);
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/tdan8/)

Comment: Look at the documentation of parent. It doesn't do what you want.

Comment: You should have put in `parents('.slider')` instead of `.parent('.slider')`.

Comment: Because `parent` take the first parent of an element. And `.slider` is not first parent of your clicked item. Use `closest` as @dystroy said or `parents()`

Answer (score -1):

You should use the parent selector, take a look on the documentation here : 
http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/

Comment: That doesn't work in this case because it is not the parent of the link that needs to animate.